# Maven downloads a dependency that is built with the newer java version than selected

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a simple java application using maven. The pom.xml is configured to use java 1.8 (and it is necessary for other reasons):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                <target>${compiler.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

...

```
<properties>
    <compiler.version>1.8</compiler.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

One of my dependencies is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

which is built using java 1.8.
When I run mvn package it fails with the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project XXX: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/gitrepo/XXX/JavaFileWriter.java:[12,30] cannot access org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException
[ERROR] bad class file: C:\Users\alt014\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\platform\org.eclipse.text\3.12.0\org.eclipse.text-3.12.0.jar(org/eclipse/jface/text/BadLocationException.class)
[ERROR] class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
[ERROR] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I already managed to find out, that org.eclipse.text-3.12.0.jar is built with java 11, so it is the reason of the error messages. But the version of org.eclipse.text is not the only one to be chosen by org.eclipse.jdt.core because org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.15.0.pom says:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.text</artifactId>
  <version>[3.6.0,4.0.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

My question is, why maven decides to select the version of org.eclipse.text that is built with the newer java version than specified and how can I avoid it. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can run `mvn dependency:tree` to get more information on your dependencies, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:tree

Comment: Maven doesn't know or care, what Java version an artifact was built. org.eclipse.text 3.12.0 is simply the latest version, so with such a version declaration, it chooses the latest one that fits.

Answer (score 0):

Maven defaults to the latest version. You need to find an older version and tell Maven to download that artifact. Maven doesn't know what version of Java was used to compile&jar the dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believe that it should help, however I don't understand one thing. The previous version org.eclipse.text-3.11.0.jar contains the following entry in the manifest file: Build-Jdk-Spec: 11. I thought that it means that it was built with java 11. That's why I thougth before that some earlier version must have been used before, when the build was working. But now I investigated it more and it seems that this version works with java 1.8. Can you explain this?

Comment: Also I noticed that the recent version org.eclipse.text-3.12.0.jar that was published last month differs from org.eclipse.text-3.11.0.jar in manifest file with another parameter Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment which is JavaSE-1.8 in version 3.11.0 and JavaSE-11 in version 3.12.0. Is it what is really taken into account by maven?